# CSS - How to address only parents and not children

Tags: css, menu, hover, parent

I have this code:

```
/*TOPMENU*/
#menu_wrap{height: 80px; width:80%; float: left; position:relative;}
#topmenu{width:100%; float:left; }
#topmenu ul{ height: 70px; padding:0; position:relative; border-style:solid;
 border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;} /* height determines distance between 2 border lines               */
#topmenu ul li{ float:left; list-style-type:none; margin:15px;} 
#topmenu ul li a{ width: 100px; line-height: 22px; text-align:center; display: block; text-decoration:none; color:#a7a9ac; font-size:25px; text-transform:uppercase} /
#topmenu ul.menu > li a:hover{ height: 50px; background:#C8C1B7; color: #fff} //when you hover on menu items
//The line above this is what I'm working on

#topmenu ul .current-menu-item a{ color:#a7a9ac;} // color of HOME font
#topmenu ul .current-menu-item ul li{ background:#1e1e1e;padding:1px 0px;}
#topmenu ul .current-menu-item ul li a{padding:4px; background:none;color:#fff;}
#topmenu ul .current-menu-parent ul .current-menu-item{background:#3e3e3e repeat;}
#topmenu ul .current-menu-parent ul .current-menu-item a{ padding:4px; background:none;}
#topmenu ul .current-menu-parent ul .current-menu-item ul .menu-item a{ padding:4px;}
#topmenu ul .current-menu-item .current-menu-item .sub-menu li a{ padding:4px;background:none;}

#topmenu ul li ul{ position:absolute;width:200px; z-index:999999; display:none; padding-left:0; margin-left:-10px;}
#topmenu ul li ul li{ float:none; margin:0; padding:0px 0px; background:#9F988F ;  display:block; }
#topmenu ul li ul li a{ color:#fff; width: 186px;font-size:10px; font-weight:normal; padding:4px;}

/* #topmenu ul li ul li a, #topmenu ul li .sub-menu .current-menu-item a:hover:hover{background:#C8C1B7; color:#ffffff;  } */
#topmenu ul li ul li ul{left: 100%; margin-top:-10px; float:none; margin-left:0px; display:none;}
```

So I'm trying to get the main menu items to have a rectangle around them when I hover over them, but that's happening to the sub menu items as well. How do I modify my code so that it only affects the main menu? I'm using a theme template so I don't have the HTML, just the CSS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your minimal HTML, and be absolutely sure that you've posted only the minimal required CSS ([sscce](http://sscce.org/) in both cases) to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the HTML it is difficult, however, you are going to need to use the direct selector in CSS..

If you are trying to apply the rectangle only to the parent `ul` only, use:

```
#topmenu > ul:hover {
    /* style */
}
```

This will apply the CSS to the `ul` which is a direct child of `#topmenu`. Therfore it won't apply it to the other children `ul`.

**UPDATED..**

Add the following..

```
#topmenu ul.menu > li li a:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

If you want it to be the same color as the background..

```
#topmenu ul.menu > li li a:hover {
    background: #C8C1B7;
}
```

Comment: ul would address the entire menu width, which results in a big rectangle over the whole thing, instead of just the menu item i hovered over.

Comment: @yahyanono Ideally, that is how you do it - Can you provide a live example..? A link - anything.

Comment: Got anything from the link I posted?

Comment: @yahyanono Where is the link..?

Comment: @yahyanono See my update.. add that CSS - let me know if it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38643/discussion-between-yahyanono-and-joshc)